# How do I perform an action on click of a particular link available on website?

Tags: android

I have an application in which I have added a menu.

Clicking on this menu opens up a website.

There is a list of links(zip files) available on this website.

Clicking on a particular link should result in that zip file to be downloaded to the assets folder of my application.

I am able to load the website.

Code for this:

```
String url = "http://almondmendoza.com/android-applications/";  
Intent k = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
k.setData(Uri.parse(url));  
startActivity(k);
```

I am referring to the example given on [this website](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026075242/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/04/open-urlwebsite-from-android.html)

What I am curious to know is whether it is possible to perform an action on click of a particular link available on the website. If it is possible then how can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WebView to load webpage, you can recognize URL using following code

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            webView.loadUrl(url); 
            // Here the String url hold 'Clicked URL' 
            return false; 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: thanks sandy for replying. i don't need to recognize url. what i want is: a website is opened(it is opening right now through the code mentioned above) with different links. clicking on a particular link should result in download of a zip file in the assets folder of my application.

Comment: referring :" whether it is possible to perform an action on click of a particular link available on website" . If you can recognize particular link, then you can perform an action using above method.